# How do I remove an entry from my JSON Object?

Tags: json, file, powershell

```
# helper to turn PSCustomObject into a list of key/value pairs
function Get-ObjectMembers {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [PSCustomObject]$obj
    )
    $obj | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {
        $key = $_.Name
        [PSCustomObject]@{Key = $key; Value = $obj."$key"}
    }
}

$entry = [PSCustomObject]@{
    PostedDate = "04/18/2018"
    JobTitle = "King"
    Street = "Bloor"
    City = "Toronto"
    DocumentURL = "../path/to/file.pdf"
}



$path = "A:\path\to\file.json"
$entry = Get-Content $path | ConvertFrom-Json

$entry

$today = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')#Get-Date -Date -format MM/dd/yyyy
$today = [datetime]::ParseExact($today, "MM/dd/yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)

foreach($date in $entry.Closing)
{
    $newdate = Get-Date $date.ToString()
    $newdate = $newdate.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
    $newdate = [datetime]::ParseExact($newdate, "MM/dd/yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)

    if($today -gt $newdate)
    {
        Write-Host $date
        #remove element from the JSON list
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how I can remove an element from the JSON Object and save a copy of the removed items as a different  JSON file

I am using PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I can't figure out how I can remove an element from the JSON Object
>   and save a copy of the removed items as a different JSON file"

You could always make use of [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6)

```
$entry | where { $_.whatever -ne 'something' } | convertto-json | out-file whatever.js
```

And to remove nodes based on property, try something like this:

```
$entry.Section.Whatever = $entry.Section.Whatever| Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Something
```

And to over-write the existing JSON object, try something like this:

```
$entry = $entry | where { $_.whatever -ne 'something' }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I don't need my foreach loop or comparing dates and I can compare the dates in the | where clause?

Comment: @softwareisfun totally possible.

Comment: In the JSON file, there is a key called "ClosingDate". I need to compare that to todays date. If the closingdate had already occured then I need to remove it from the JSON file and keep track of the removed entry in a new output.json file. I don't get how I would be able to perform the date comparisons

Comment: "I can't figure out how I can remove an element from the JSON Object and save a copy of the removed items as a different JSON file", my example does exactly that. You need to update your question. Just plug my code into your commented line.

Comment: your response changes the logic of my code which brings up a new question as a result.

Comment: @softwareisfun did you try it?

Comment: Thanks it did create a new file with the entry. How would I remove that same entry from the existing file?

Comment: @softwareisfun you could try to specify your current file, instead of "whatever.js" in the example. You may have to force it, but I think that should work too. Keep in mind, you will have to "reset" $entry value, with the new value.

Comment: @softwareisfun also, if you look at this reddit thread, there is a solution in it, on how to remove JSON nodes: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2sem64/powershell_json/

Answer (score 1):

If we look at our JSon object $Entry it looks like this:

```
PostedDate  : 04/18/2018
JobTitle    : King
Street      : Bloor
City        : Toronto
DocumentURL : ../path/to/file.pdf
```

and in Powershell the JSon object is a PSCustomObject:

```
$Entry.gettype().fullName
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

so we coud remove selected object elements like this:

```
$entry.PSObject.Properties.Remove("NameOfElementWeWantToRemove")
```

so in the case of 'PostedDate', would look like this:

```
$entry.psobject.properties.remove("PostedDate")
```

Now the $entry object looks like this:

```
JobTitle    : King
Street      : Bloor
City        : Toronto
DocumentURL : ../path/to/file.pdf
```

and the 'PostedDate' has been dropped.

So really it's a simple one liner,

Have fun!